# Symfony doctrine and stored procedure

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony1, doctrine, schema

I try to learn symfony by this [tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/)

And is very good guide.
But know im want to create stored procedure.
And how i can describe procedures in shema yaml files?
Because when i try to ./symfony doctrine:build --all -and-load - doctrine drop my database and i lose all my procedures

Comment: Then don't run that command, --all includes the drop-db command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How i can see all command that include --all command or other?

Comment: `php symfony help doctrine:build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot describe stored procedures in doctrine's yaml schema. However, you can do that in sql, and with the help in [this post from Jonathan Wage](http://jwage.com/2010/07/27/executing-sql-after-loading-your-data-fixtures-in-symfony-1-4/) you can execute that sql after loading your fixtures.

Comment: Illustrating why answers are better than links, here's that post on the wayback machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120702074144/http://jwage.com/2010/07/27/executing-sql-after-loading-your-data-fixtures-in-symfony-1-4/

Answer (score 0):

hy,
I have a procedure under sql server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]
-- Variables d'entrée
@p_ENL_I_ID                 int,
-- Variables de retour
@p_RETURN_STATUS            int output
AS
BEGIN
if @p_ENL_I_ID >5   
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS= 6
end
else
begin
    SET @p_RETURN_STATUS=2
end
END
```

and my code for call this procédure :

```
$query = "{CALL TEST(:p_ENL_I_ID,  :p_RETURN_STATUS) }";
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$nativeQuery = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($query, $rsm);
$nativeQuery->setParameters(array('p_ENL_I_ID'=> 8 ,'p_RETURN_STATUS' => '' ));
$result= $nativeQuery->getResult();
```

the procedure works but I have an error :
exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields

how to retrieve return variable @p_RETURN_STATUS  ?

Thank !
Cédric

Comment: This is a place for answers, if you have a question just create a new one if the answer you're looking for is not already on so

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31696744)